# How do I import a custom map into UE4?

Tags: unreal-4, maya

I have seen videos on creating the map/level in UE4, but not how to import the map from something like maya. Would I have to import it as an object? I have been playing around in the editor but haven't been able to find any setting that seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your map from Maya (or any other tool) as an FBX file. Ensure your scale is centimeters, or the map will be incorrectly scaled in Unreal. Now open Unreal, right-click in the Content Browser, and select Import.

Be aware that you cannot change map layout using this method; if you find errors or changes needed in layout or flow, you will need to make those changes in the external tool then reimport the FBX.

Comment: If I made its lights in maya would they export as well? Or would just the map?

Comment: Just the map, Unreal would import everything as geometry not entities. You could bake lighting onto textures or vertex colors and use that ingame, but it's an extra hassle if the model geometry needs alteration.